# How MATLAB's "if" function handles multiple inputs

Tags: matlab

I ran a quick test to see how `if` deals with multiple input values.  It appears that the default behavior is to apply `and` to the collection of values, but I couldn't find any documentation.  Can anyone confirm or provide a counterexample?

```
>> if([1,1,1]) disp(sprintf('hi'));end;
hi
>> if([1]) disp(sprintf('hi'));end;
hi
>> if([1,1,0]) disp(sprintf('hi'));end;
```

EDIT: to clarify,  I don't intend to try to use this "feature," but wanted to be sure I knew how erroneous input would be handled.  Suppose, for example, your code read 
`if(my_function)`  and the (badly written) `my_function` usually returns a single value but occasionally returns multiple values.  Good practice, of course , would parse the returned values appropriately and feed a single value to `if`.

Comment: From the documentation for [`if`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html): `An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise, the expression is false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find any practical reason to create an `if` statement which depends on anything but a scalar.

Regarding what's done in MATLAB practically?
You may assume MATLAB applies the function [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) on the input of the `if` statement.
This will hold as intuition given the array is non empty.

For example, if we have array - `array4Example` which is not empty, the statement `if` on the array - `if(array4Example)` is equivalent of the statement if on the scalar - `if(all(array4Example(:)))`.

This matches the documentation if the [`if`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) function.

Comment: Not exactly. `all([])` is `true`, whereas `if []` evaluates to `false`. See @excaza's description in the comment above

Comment: I think using all matches his comment. The `if` statement is regarded true only if all elements are different than 0. This is also the case for `all`. Of course it is assumed to be non empty.

Comment: Again: compare `if all([]) 1, else 2, end` with `if [] 1, else 2, end`

Comment: Hi, I wrote above, it requires the input not to be empty. Empty is the only extreme case. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: I think the answer is clearer now (+1). I would also add explicitly that if the expression produces an empty result it always evaluates to `false` (from the point of view of `if`)